text attribute in .gitattributes and git config core.autocrlf

If the text attribute is unspecified, Git uses the core.autocrlf configuration variable to determine if the file should be converted.

From this statement, text attribute should override the core.autocrlf config but I have the following observation. eol attribute or core.eol is unspecified for both PC.
The file has LF endings in the remote.
Why does it happen?

Isn't it text attribute should override the core.autocrlf config?
Isn't it core.autocrlf=input only affect the check in?


On PC 1 (Windows 11), * text=auto and core.autocrlf=false, the file is checkout as CRLF endings


On PC 2 (Windows 10), * text=auto and core.autocrlf=input, the file is checkout as LF endings


Note that auto also has a description -- and to my knowledge, this is the actual default behavior. The eol conversion then depends on the eol attribute. I would say the sentence you quote from the doc (the Unspecifued paragraph for text) is misleading.

Upon checkout, auto attribute only decide whether the eol conversion should be done. The actual conversion depends on the eol attribute, LF or CRLF. Since the eol attribute is unspecified, it considers core.eol and core.autocrlf. On PC2, core.autocrlf is input, so core.eol is ignored and the file is checkout as LF. On PC1, core.autocrlf is false, core.eol is considered and its default value is native (CRLF). Is my understanding correct?

yes, I reach the same conclusion as you after re-reading git help config for core.autocrlf and core.eol


On PC 2 (Windows 10), * text=auto and core.autocrlf=input, the file is checkout as LF endings

core.autocrlf=input is used for MacOs, on windows you should set it to true true
CRLF fast review



Setting
Repo
Working tree




core.autocrlf=true
LF
CRLF


core.autocrlf=input
LF
Leaving original



core.autocrlf=input
This value will leave the eol in its original value on the worktree most common: LF but can also be CRLF if you're viewing a file you created on Windows)



why core.autocrlf=input will lead to different checkout behavior?
